# Differences between 2 times?

Tags: c#

```
StartCopying = DateTime.Now;
File.Copy(@"C:\Users\sshap5x\Desktop\line4\shiraDebbi\Hackers.avi", @"C:\Users\sshap5x\Desktop\test\Hackers.avi", true);

EndCopying = DateTime.Now;
CopyingTime1 = (endCopying - startCopying).Duration;
```

What is the problem with my code?

Copying time is TimeSpan object.

Comment: I suggest formatting your code to make it easier to read.

Comment: Also, what errors \ exceptions are you getting?

Comment: It might be better if you told us what the problem is? Are you getting an error, is the result of the subtraction incorrect?

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is you're trying to solve. Apart from the case-sensitive difference between EndCopying and endCopying, looks like you're doing a standard  (endTime - startTime) time computation.

Comment: We don't know what the problem is. I'm guessing that it causes an error. In order for this to be a complete question, you'll need to provide the Exception details.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything *wrong*; but I would suggest using a `Stopwatch` instead. This is a purpose-built class for measuring elapsed times.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

Comment: Problem is a big first letters in StartCopying and EndCopying :)

Comment: The problem with your code is, that is isn't complete so nobody could reproduce your problem which leads us to the question, what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// This prints 0.1 (roughly)
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
Thread.Sleep(100);
var diff = DateTime.Now - start;
Console.WriteLine(diff.TotalSeconds);
```

In your code (which wouldn't even compile) you use `.Duration` as a property when it is in fact a method. In any case, you don't need to call Duration at all because the result returned by the subtraction is a `TimeSpan` containing the difference. You can then get this diff in whatever format you need (milliseconds, seconds, hours, days, etc.).

The only need for the [Duration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.duration.aspx) method is if you are unsure whether the result is negative or positive.

Answer (score 5):

The assignments are to `StartCopying` and `EndCopying` but your read the data from other variables `startCopying` and `endCopying`.
C# is case sensitive.
And also Duration is a method. so you need to use `.Duration()`
And as suggested in the comments to your question, for better resolution use the `Stopwatch` class.

Comment: how do i use the stopwach class?

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget the () for Duration and capitalisation for the variables EndCopying and StartCopying?

```
        DateTime StartCopying = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime EndCopying = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan CopyingTime1 = (EndCopying - StartCopying).Duration();
```